# Building cross-platform(Linux, Windows) java JNI application with maven

Tags: java, maven, java-native-interface, native

I want to build Java application which uses JNI and code in C. Moreover I want make my app cross-platform by compiling native code and packaging native platform-dependent libraries within JAR file. I was following [this guide](http://www.tricoder.net/blog/?p=197) 
but it is not working. I have no examples with maven-native-plugin nor NAR plugins. How is it possible to make java native methods cross-platform?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to check the [nar-maven-plugin](http://maven-nar.github.io/) for example.